Warning "bugprone-exception-escape" when captured object throws in copy constructor
When I have a C++ lambda that captures an object by value, and that object can throw an exception in its copy constructor, clang-tidy will show a warning:

warning: an exception may be thrown in function
'(lambda at :15:23)' which should not throw exceptions
[bugprone-exception-escape]

I don't understand why this warning appears.
Example code:
#include <functional>

class MyClass {
   public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) { throw std::exception(); }
    void do_stuff() const {}
};

void inner_func(std::function<void()>&& the_func) {}

void outer_func() {
    MyClass test_obj;

    auto the_lambda = [=]() { test_obj.do_stuff(); };
    inner_func(std::move(the_lambda));
}

(on godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/67xW6Yenx)
The clang-tidy warning is shown for the line where the_lambda is created.
I don't understand why the lambda (or creating the lambda) must not throw exceptions. In the example, outer_func() does not care whether an exception happens. inner_func() also should not care about this.
Also, apparently the lambda needs to be std::move()d into another function for the warning to appear.
So it seems that merely creating the lambda is a problem already. But why is that the case? And how can I catch this exception that is warned about, or how else can I avoid the warning?
On Godbolt I tried this with clang-tidy 16 and 19, with same results.

Your example can be simplified: https://godbolt.org/z/rWeq7hKdq

BTW, there is an additional example without lambdas: https://godbolt.org/z/hze55P9Gb.

The warning is triggered because the closure type of the_lambda has a throwing move constructor. And, as others pointed out, one of the purposes of this check is to report throwing move constructors.
Why is the move constructor of the_lambda throwing? Because it internally calls the copy constructor of MyClass, which can throw. Note that the move constructor of a closure type is defaulted [expr.prim.lambda.closure/14/2], which makes it defined here as throwing.
A simple demo of the same problem without lambdas:
struct MyClass {
  MyClass() {}
  MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) { throw 1; }
};

struct Lambda {
  MyClass myclass;

  Lambda(MyClass param) : myclass(param) { }
  Lambda(const Lambda&) = default;
  Lambda(Lambda&&) = default;  // this calls throwing copy constructor of `MyClass`
};

void outer_func() {
  MyClass obj;
  Lambda l1(obj);
  Lambda l2(std::move(l1));  // this calls throwing move constructor of 'Lambda'
}

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/hze55P9Gb

Ok, so the lessons are: a) If clang-tidy shows a warning for function '(lambda at ...)', the warning is actually about the "synthetic" class behind the lambda. b) The compiler will only generate a move constructor for a lambda if it is actually moved (so adding a std::move() call further below can introduce such a warning in an earlier line). c) Exactly which of the generated functions of the lambda (destructor, move constructor, move assignment operator) caused the warning cannot be determined from the warning message, I guess?

@oliver It seems so. When I used my Lambda class, the warning pointed out to the defaulted definition of the move constructor. But for a closure type, there is no such definition in the code. Also, I have no idea why the warning refers to the previous line, and not the one where he initialization by the move constructor is caused (this doesn't make any sense). I would suggest asking about this issue at some vendor's forum related to the clang-tidy tool.

The manual describes when the warning is raised. MyClass doesn't have a non throwing move constructor because the class have a user defined copy constructor. The compiler has to call the throwing copy constructor when moveing the_lambda to the_func.

This doesn't explain "why the lambda (or creating the lambda) must not throw exceptions", which is the core of the question.

@PeteBecker What to explain if creating the lambda is not a subject of the warning?

Of course the lambda is the subject of the warning. It's reported exactly on capture list of the lambda. And your explanation doesn't match documentation - the warning should be reported on throwing move constructor, not on throwing copy constructor which inhibits implicit move constructor.

@Yksisarvinen There is no any move constructor especially there is no a throwing move construct. The throwing copy constructor is called when a non throwing move is expected to be performed. And read the question carefully: the lambda needs to be std::move()d into another function for the warning to appear. The warning is not a subject of a capture list of the lambda.

@3CxEZiVlQ -- the warning says "should not throw exceptions" and the question is "why is throwing exceptions here a bad thing?" From your most recent comment, why is "a non throwing move ... expected"?

@PeteBecker The question that I answer is I don't understand why this warning appears. If the post has multiple questions this should not be a claim to me and the post should be closed as need more focus.

IF the Q should be closed you shouldn't be answering it.

@3CxEZiVlQ -- now you're being tendentious. The question is clear. You didn't answer it.

@3CxEZiVlQ "There is no any move constructor especially there is no a throwing move construct." But there is a trowing move constructor.
